# Site mapping tool

Tags: software-recommendation

I need to map a website that has over 200 webpages. There are number of tools do so on Windows, like [Site Visualiser](http://site-visualizer.com/en/visual-sitemap), or [PowerMapper](http://www.powermapper.com); Miscrosoft Visio also seems able to [crawl a web site and produce a map](http://www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=454165) out of it.

Is there anything similar for Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

### Not actually used any, But you can give them a try....

[power mapper alternative for linux](https://alternativeto.net/software/powermapper/?platform=linux)

[npm tool for site mapping](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sitemap-generator-cli)

[Optimus Sitemap Generator](https://patrickmn.com/projects/osg/)

Comment: Of those only OSG actually functions, but it produces a flat list of pages, not a tree or a map.